# Можно ли склеить токены (строки) в препроцессоре и получить токен (имя константы)?

Tags: c, token, препроцессор

```
#define Choose A
#define Const Argument

#define ArgumentA 0x31
#define ArgumentB 0x32

#define FinalArgument (Const ## Choose )
```

Получается FinalArgument (ConstChoose)

А надо бы что бы получилось FinalArgument(ArgumentA)

Возможно ли такое? Если нет, как правильно решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что при склеивании токены не раскрываются. Для того, чтобы раскрыть их, вам нужно использовать лишний промежуточный макрос:

```
#define Choose A
#define Const Argument

#define ArgumentA 0x31
#define ArgumentB 0x32

#define PASTE_EXPANDED(x, y) PASTE(x, y)
#define PASTE(x, y) x ## y

#define FinalArgument (PASTE_EXPANDED(Const, Choose))
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/5xYGmx

Comment: Спасибо большое. Весьма не очевидное решение.

Comment: Это да, сишный препроцессор совершенно неинтуитивен. Я в более-менее сложных случаях предпочитаю генерацию исходников маленьким скриптом.

Comment: @ReasonX: Пожалуйста!